# Python Selenium Webdriver to test highcharts

Tags: python, selenium, highcharts

Is there any way to test highcharts given in attached [file](https://icok8q.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pQtqH6FUY7283ptbNSVs2hmXtc-nwhhcDpmfHc73yU7mlPh674cW98jqXm1n_nCjDjFrw14zAamnOGV0y04HFrw/disk_cap.html?download&psid=1) using selenium webdriver in python?

Comment: I want to read the values plotted by graph. Can anyone help me reading any one of these graphs?? Reading page source won't work as the data is generated by some javascript.... I am not sure if we need to execute jquery on SVG path...

Comment: please edit your question instead of commenting it... Just looked up highcharts.com and I guess you can get information out of them. But it seems not that easy. Have you thought of taking screenshots?

Comment: Why not read from the javascript code that is used to create the chart? The series data is there. If it is an ajax call you would probably have to also push out what the values are to some var

Comment: Do you want me to execute the same javascript function from selenium and capture the result for further processing? If so, have the script be  executed using jquery???